# Can't reach some lines debugging android app

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to debug my app in my phone but Android Studio can't see some parts of my code as executable with the warning:

No executable code found at line XX in class ...

[image]

Following is the image of the breakpoints, I try to debug line by line bug it just skips the lines with the X breakpoints. I tried to debug in eclipse and got the same behavior.

Using:

- Android Studio 0.4.2
- LG G2
- Android 4.2.2

[image: Debugging]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805868/android-studio-debugger-highlights-the-wrong-lines/21866797#21866797 . It's a limitation in dx and there's nothing you can really do about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try to disable code shrinking in your build.gradle file. it's located in your projects root directory.
Under buildTypes, make sure minifyEnabled is set to false. should look something like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me and makes complete sense.

Comment: Didn't work for me! I am trying to put a break point inside Failure method of a CallBack to see whats the error. :(

Comment: did not worked for me ... debugger skipping for loop after creation of jsonarray object ... please help

Comment: I thought `debuggable true` was the default value for `debug`, but indeed the debugger worked after adding it.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue while working on my project. I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and I solved the issue by cleaning the project.

Go to Build --> Clean project

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers from the many posts on this topic worked for me. I am using AndroidStudio2.

I had been running my code using the `Debug 'app' (Shift+F9)` button ...

then I tried using the normal `Run 'app' (Shift+F10)` button, followed by the `Attach debugger to Android process` button, and all the red break point circles with x's turned to checks.

After I `run`'d it that once, I went back to `debug`ing it, and the break points continued to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Menu Run -> Clean and Rerun.

After building and deploying, start Debug again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using build variants open BuildVariants Tab(mostly it will be on left side of android studio), select debug for the particular module

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps

1) Clean project

2)Rebuild project

3) close Android Studio

4) Restart Android Studio.