# Java code executing incorrectly when debugging with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I have this code in my Android app:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == POST_VIEW_TYPE){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(App.instance).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }else{
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(App.instance).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

The code basically gets a constant named `viewType`, and inflates the correct view accordingly. My constant `POST_VIEW_TYPE` is equal to `1`:

[image]

So far so good. I am passing `viewType` as `1` to my handler, but the code is somehow evaluating the `else` branch even though the (extremely simple) expression in `if` evaluates to `true` (obviously):

[image]

How is this even possible?

**UPDATE:** I've cleaned the project and rebuilt, but nothing has changed. I've put a breakpoint on the if statement. Here is a GIF demonstrating as I step through the debugger:

[image]

Comment: try cleaning your project and run again, in case if u have not tried.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the `if(viewType == POST_VIEW_TYPE){` line

Comment: @chandil03 tried, still the same, see my updated question

Comment: @krzyk I've added. it apparently enters the if branch, steps through the return and jumps down to the body of the else. I know it sounds silly, but see the GIF in my updated question.

Comment: Are you ending up with the correct `View`s in your `RecyclerView` anyway? Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805868/android-studio-debugger-highlights-the-wrong-lines).

Comment: Sometimes the debugger does this, but the result is correct its just a bug in the debugger :(

Comment: copy that `onCreateViewHOlder()` method and put it after `onBindViewHolder()` mrthod. Some time these silly things solves problem.

Comment: @MikeM. you were correct, it's the same thing, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, thanks to Mike M. pointing out to a similar issue at [Android Studio debugger highlights the wrong lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805868/android-studio-debugger-highlights-the-wrong-lines).

Apparently, correct code *was* executing, but because a completely irrelevant bug was present in my code somewhere else, it was masking the issue, and because debugger was behaving incorrectly, I've simply thought there was something going on related to this issue. I've fixed the other bug, and changed my code in `onCreateViewHolder` to this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(viewType == POST_VIEW_TYPE){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(App.instance).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
        holder = new PostViewHolder(view);
    }else{
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(App.instance).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        holder = new UserViewHolder(view);
    }
    return holder;
}
```

It now works (and debugs) correctly. It's interesting to see Google's own IDE for Android can't step through (and doesn't even display a warning telling that debugging may step incorrectly due to multiple return paths) the code that Dalvik produces. I wish ART has solved this issue.