# Android Studio debugging does unusual things

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I have written this simple method in my activity in Android Studio:

[image]

I did not work correctly. I tried the debugging mode to figure out the error. As it is shown, there is no variable 'b' in Variables table, Watches table and even on my mouse over.

**The next surprising thing is that when I do Step Over, not only it does not come out of the method using return, but also it goes to the next return line after the last else statement.**

**Edit:** The return issue is fixed using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805868/android-studio-debugger-highlights-the-wrong-lines) but the 'b' variable still is the problem. so it is not duplicate to that one.

I have also tried closing and reopening my Android Studio.

The version of my Android Studio is 2.1, my JRE is 1.8 and I am on Windows 10 Pro.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. The return issue is fixed using the link but the 'b' variable still is the problem.

Comment: could you try to delete the build folder and recompile your project.. 
it should fix your issue

Comment: @vladsol no it did not work.

Comment: I downgraded to android studio 1.2 and it fixed. it is not a duplicate please let me answer my own question.