# Android studio not executing latest code

Tags: android, android-studio

I have done some modifications to my code which upon running, Android studio behaves exactly the way it was before my changes.

As I place debug points on those new lines, I get a weird error message stating "No executable code found at line xx"

Following is a snapshot of the same. How do I resolve this issue ?

[image: See attachment]

Edit: I have already tried Invalidate caches and restart, still stands unresolved.

Comment: `Rebuild`, if still not resolved then `Invalidate Cache/Restart` from `File` menu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't reach some lines debugging android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743442/cant-reach-some-lines-debugging-android-app)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Already tried the same before posting question. Still stands unresolved

Comment: @AMRUTHAKALIVARAPU Have you tried moving the codes from that line to other lines ?

Comment: Yes. I have uninstalled the old apk and re-run which finally worked.

Comment: Try to disable Instant Run :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It possible caused by AndroidStudio's new feature `Instant Run`. Try to stop current app, hit build->rebuild project then run app again.

Comment: You  can disable it from the Instant run settings.